# Two minipages side-by-side, bold caption title, and underfull warning

Tags: boxes, minipage, warnings

Is there a way to fix a `main.tex:11: Underfull \hbox (badness 2409) (page 1)` for the following `main.tex` file?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!t]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption[Top1 \emph{vs.}\ network]{
      \textbf{Top1 \emph{vs.}\ network.}
      \lipsum[1]
    }
    \label{fig:top1_vs_net}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption[Top1 \emph{vs.}\ operations, size $\propto$ parameters]{
      \textbf{Top1 \emph{vs.}\ operations, size $\propto$ parameters.}
      \lipsum[1]
    }
    \label{fig:top1_vs_ops}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX output]

I believe the warning is associated to the caption "title" of Figure 1. Anyways, how does one debug this stuff?

Comment: you can see the text is underfull just looking at your image where the  white space in the first line of the caption is over-stretched. Justified text in narrow captions is tricky, you could just ignore the warning, or tell tex not to complain about that level of badness or you could change the formatting of the caption to ragged right

Comment: It is recommended to use `raggedright` option while typesetting in narrow columns. Also, don't forget to allow a lot of hyphenation to get not waved, but ragged edge.

Comment: Oh... what about adding a `\newline` for some specific lines? Or this highly not advisable, since it is going to create a mess, if I'm going to change layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the small line width for captions. You can either help LaTeX to hyphenate words, or add to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[figure]{justification=RaggedRight}
```

so the caption lines will be ragged right when  LaTeX can't find a correct break point:

[image]